# Doc reference warning for java docs

Tags: java, javadoc

The following is a Java Doc for one of my methods . But [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html) is giving a warning message for the `@see` section

```
   /**
     * Clears the selections on all the tables containig view sub types except the currently selected one
     * @param exceptControl index of the sub type table whose selection needs to be preserved
     * @see ViewSubTypeHandler#clearSubTypeTableSelection()
     */


Warning : Doc reference clearSubTypeTableSelection not found.
```

What is this warning message and how can I fix this ?

This is the code for the method for which the warning has been raised :

```
 private void clearSubTypeTableSelection(boolean resetAll, int exceptControl) {
        if (!resetAll) {
            clearAllExceptCurrent(exceptControl);
        } else {
            clearAll();
        }

    }
```

And this is the method for the javadoc in question:

```
private void clearAllExceptCurrent(int exceptControl) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SUBTYPE_TABLES; i++)
        if (i != exceptControl && getSubTypeTable(i).getSelectedRowKeys() != null) {
            RichTable richTable = getSubTypeTable(i);
            RowKeySet rowkeySet = richTable.getSelectedRowKeys();
            rowkeySet.clear();
            AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(richTable);
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `import` statement for `ViewSubTypeHandler`  is missing?

Comment: What's the signature of that method in code?

Comment: @Fildor I have put the code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is `clearSubTypeTableSelection(boolean resetAll, int exceptControl)`

not `clearSubTypeTableSelection()`

You must specify the arguments (type):

```
 * @see ViewSubTypeHandler#clearSubTypeTableSelection(boolean, int)
```